# CSS column break problems with Chrome 64

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I cannot get Chrome 64 to do my column breaks properly.

Here is an example chunk of HTML:

```
<tr><TD>
<div class="keeptogether">
<table class="header">
<tr><td><a href=#missing onclick="toggle('general-catalogue-composer0')">
<B>Willoughby Bertie, 4th Earl of Abingdon<font size=-2> (1740 - 1799)
</font></B></a></TD></TR>
<TR><td>
<div id = "general-catalogue-composer0"  style="display: none;">
<table class="detail">
<tr><td>
All hail to the myrtle shade. T.T.T.Kbd..&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href=http://www.notamos.co.uk/detail.php?scoreid=145425 
target=_blank>Play/print/buy</a>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
Where shall a hapless lover find. T.T.T.Kbd..&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href=http://www.notamos.co.uk/detail.php?scoreid=145427
target=_blank>Play/print/buy</a>
</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</td></tr>
```

The four columns contain many of these, each with one header row and varying numbers of detail rows.
The onclick function toggles display of the detail rows for the relevant header (i.e., for the specific detail rows shown above, the div with id general-catalogue-composer0).
The div with class keeptogether should contain no column breaks.

Here is the relevant CSS stuff (the list above gets its columns via class menuindex):

```
.detail {
    font-size: 8px;
}
.header {
    font-size: 10px;
}
.menuindex, .menuchoral-sacred, .menuchoral-profane, .menuinstrumental {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
}
.keeptogether {
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
}
```

It all works perfectly on the latest versions of Edge and IE - when I click on a header the detail lines appear and the columns re-jig themselves so that there are no detail lines at the tops of columns. On Chrome this simply does not happen - the display toggle is fine but Chrome appears to add column breaks wherever it likes.

My understanding is that Chrome 64 is supposed to support the CSS setup I have used.

Any ideas gratefully received!

P.S. I ended up successfully using flexbox to provide the necessary column breaks.

Comment: Post edited as requested, although in my opinion flexbox did provide a genuine answer in that it has fully resolved my problem.

Comment: I gather that because this post attracted a 'Tumbleweed' badge there is some danger of its being deleted at some point. This seems a shame as I would have thought it might be useful to /someone/ at some point (I'd usually expect questions on forums to remain available from a knowledge base perspective).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested with your TABLE code, but working with bullet lists, if you have the -webkit-columns CSS on the outer element (UL) and the -webkit-column-break-inside on the inner (LI) it works correctly in Chrome 64.  Perhaps using a list rather than a table (if possible) would be an option.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding on this. I ended up using flexbox to provide the necessary column breaks instead (which worked a treat) but would otherwise definitely have made the change you suggest.